# Evitar fugas de memoria C#

Tags: c#, manejo-de-memoria, árboles-binarios

Tengo una clase para hacer un árbol que se puede recorrer hacia arriba y hacia abajo, teniendo como referencia al nodo padre, algo así:

```
public class Nodo
{
  protected List<Nodo> Hijos...
  public Nodo Padre....

  public void Add(Nodo nodo)
  {
     nodo.Padre = this;
     Hijos.add(nodo)
  }
}
```

Para borrar un nodo hago lo siguiente

```
public void Borra(int index)
{
  if(index < Hijos.count){
    Hijos[index].Padre = null;
    Hijos.RemoveAt(index);
  }
}
```

Suponiendo que tengo un árbol donde el nodo raíz tiene dos hijos y a su vez el primer nodo de la raiz tiene un hijo anidado, algo asi:

```
Raiz
|-Nodo_1
| |- Nodo_1_2
|-Nodo_2
```

Al borrar "Nodo_1" ¿tendré una fuga de memoria? ya que "Nodo_1_2" hace referencia a su padre el "Nodo_1"

No he querido hacer una función recursiva para eliminar todas las referencias a los padres de una rama eliminada, ya que podría tener arboles grandes y no se si sería una tarea innecesaria.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que eliminar de forma recursiva, algo como ser

```
public void Eliminar(Nodo nodo){

    List<Nodo> temp = new List<Nodo>();

    foreach(Nodo item in nodo.Hijos){

       if(item.Hijos != null 
            && item.Hijos.Count > 0){
          Eliminar(item); 
       }

       item.Padre = null;
       temp.Add(item);
    }

    foreach(var item in temp){
      nodo.Hijos.Remove(item);
    }

}
```

es necesario la lista `temp` ya que el `foreach` no permite remover mientras se itera, por eso se realiza en un loop separado

Revisa como en el loop que itera los hijo se invoca a `Eliminar()` de forma recursiva asi vas quitando si los desendientes tienen tambie hijos

Comment: Gracias por la implementación, lo que realmente quería saber es que tan necesario es hacer esa función para eliminar todos los nodos hijos, si realmente el GC podría limpiar la memoria con solo eliminar un nodo de la lista padre

Comment: Si puede asegurar que ninguna variable tendra referencia a la instancia de ese nodo entonces el GC lo recolectara, entiendo que si eliminas un nodo root los hijos tambien se reciclaran cuando lo haga el nodo padre. Igualmente no esta de mas pensar en una eliminacion recursiva

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunas pruebas y vi que (al menos en éste caso) no es necesario eliminar la referencia hacia el padre, parece que C# administra muy bien los recursos.

Hice la prueba de la siguiente forma:

Al objeto nodo le agregué dos atributos para poder identificarlo: Nivel e Index y agregué un destructor para verificar que el nodo sea eliminado

```
    ~Nodo()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Matando hijo "+Index+" del nivel " + Nivel);
    }
```

Después genero un árbol, donde el nodo root tiene tres hijos y al segundo hijo le agrego otro nodo hijo y a éste le agrego 10 más

```
Nodo root = new Nodo();
root.Add();
root.Add();
root.Add();

root[1].Add();
root[1][0].Add();
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    root[1][0].Add();
```

Después al borrar el segundo nodo, quien tiene mayor profundidad veo que sale en el log cada nodo eliminado al forzar el llamado del GC:

```
root.Del(1);
GC.Collect();
```

Consola:

```
Matando hijo 4 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 3 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 2 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 1 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 0 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 8 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 1 del nivel 1
Matando hijo 0 del nivel 2
Matando hijo 7 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 10 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 9 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 6 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 5 del nivel 3
```

Para descartar errores guarde el nodo eliminado en otra variable temporal y efectivamente al invocar al GC no apareció nada en la consola

```
temp = root[1];
root.Del(1);
GC.Collect();
```

Después puse en null la variable temp, llame al GC y volvió a aparecer en consola cada nodo eliminado

```
temp = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Consola:

```
Matando hijo 4 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 3 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 2 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 1 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 0 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 8 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 1 del nivel 1
Matando hijo 0 del nivel 2
Matando hijo 7 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 10 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 9 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 6 del nivel 3
Matando hijo 5 del nivel 3
```

**El porque**

Pues resulta que aunque los nodos hijos tengan una referencia al nodo padre, ésta referencia es una referencia débil (WeakReference) ya que el nodo hijo esta en el Heap.

En la primer prueba, cuando se elimina el nodo[1](https://luisnet.azurewebsites.net/2018/08/05/weakreference-en-c/) ya no hay nadie en el stack que haga referencia éste, entonces el GC lo elimina junto con todos sus descendientes, aunque existen referencias entre el nodo[1](https://luisnet.azurewebsites.net/2018/08/05/weakreference-en-c/) y sus hijos, éstas referencias están dentro del Heap, por lo tanto, son candidatos a eliminarse.

En la prueba 2 se está pasando la referencia del nodo[1](https://luisnet.azurewebsites.net/2018/08/05/weakreference-en-c/) a la variable temp la cual si está en el stack, por lo tanto, el nodo[1](https://luisnet.azurewebsites.net/2018/08/05/weakreference-en-c/) y sus hijos no serán eliminados hasta que temp se iguale a null.

[Aqui](https://luisnet.azurewebsites.net/2018/08/05/weakreference-en-c/) hay una mejor explicación de las referencias débil